# How to set default back UINavigationItem for specific UIViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a `UIViewController` which is displayed differently depending on context:

- as `UINavigationController`'s first controller *(no back navigation bar)*
- as `UINavigationController`'s top controller *(back navigation bar)*
- as the one of the two `UISplitViewController`'s controllers

But I need there a different icon than the default one. To avoid to check the context and assign it or not every time, I would like to show the controller how does it loooks like, and it assign it by itself, when it is needed.

Is it possible? If so, what should I do?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly. I think you do need to check every time. Are you trying to ask whether there is better logic to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `UIViewController` properties to determine where your view controller is in the view controller hierarchy. The two in particular are `splitViewController` and `navigationController`.

`splitViewController` returns the nearest `UISplitViewController` ancestor in the view controller hierarchy. If there is none, the property is `nil`.

`navigationController` is essentially the same thing as `splitViewController`. It returns the nearest `UINavigationController` ancestor in the view controller hierarchy and is `nil` if there is none that exists.

Here's how you would determine which of the 3 scenarios your view controller is in (assuming there are no other scenarios):

```
if let splitVC = viewController.splitViewController {
    // split view controller scenario
} else if let navigationVC = viewController.navigationController {

    if navigationVC.viewControllers[0] == viewController {
        // first controller scenario (no back button)
    } else if navigationVC.topViewController == viewController {
        // top controller scenario (back button)
    }

}
```